# jQuery - If input element has this class then change another class

Tags: jquery, input, credit-card

My shopping cart already recognizes the card type and changes the "Change-CC-Type" (the Change-CC-Type would actually be amex, visa or mastercard) in the input block to match the card type. So I want a script to find the `class="Change-CC-Type"` and then change the `<i class="fa-credit-card">` so I can have it change the class to the matching card type.

```js
$('#an-cc-number').keyup(function() {
  if ($('#an-cc-number').hasClass('Change-CC-Type')) {
    $('#FA-CC').addClass('fa-cc-amex');
    $('#FA-CC').removeClass('fa-credit-card');
  } else {
    $('#FA-CC').removeClass('fa-cc-amex');
    $('#FA-CC').addClass('fa-credit-card');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="tel" class="form-control Change-CC-Type" id="an-cc-number" placeholder="Card Number" />
<i id="FA-CC" class="fa-regular fa-credit-card"></i>
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Comment: It would help if you added CSS to the snippet so we can see the result of changing the class